# Node.js and express: attachment on nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I'd like to attach a file on the email using Nodemailer. I tried several ways following this guide: https://nodemailer.com/using-attachments/, with .pdf, .txt...but nothing worked.
Any ideas?
This is my code with the last try:

```
router.post('/profilocliente/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Customer.findById(req.params.id, function(err, customer){
    if(err) throw err;
    var mailOptions={
      to : customer.email,
      subject : req.body.oggetto,
      text : req.body.testo,
      attachments: [{path: 'C:/Users/Angelo/Desktop/test.txt'}]
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smptTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
      }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.redirect('/clienti/profilocliente/'+customer._id);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue don't know why not able to send the file from desktop. Keep it in D drive and out side from project directory  below is my code

```
exports.sendmail=function (to,subject,text,html,info) {


var mailOptions = {
    attachments: [

        {   // file on disk as an attachment
            filename: 'ab.txt',
            path: 'D:/ab.txt' // stream this file
            //below one not working some time dont know why but its work for me now
             path: 'C:/Users/Me/Desktop/ab.txt'
            //this also work foo me
            path: 'D:/myproject/files/ab.txt'
        }],
    from: '"Testing Mail" <sender@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: to, // list of receivers
    subject: subject, // Subject line
    text: text, // plaintext body
    html: html  // html body
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, infoo){
    var res={
        responsecode:''
    }
    if(error){
        res.responsecode=401;
        return info(new Error(res.responsecode),null);
    }
    res.responsecode=200;
    info(null,res.responsecode+infoo.response);
});}
```

[image]